# Why do I received UDP socket answer randomly with Asynchronous UDP client socket?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, udpclient

I have a code there send a XML file to a UdpSocket and received an answer. I send and received the answer Asynchronous. My problem is, when I received the answer from UDP socket, I cannot save it to the right file. I have tried a lot of things, but nothing works.

To explain my code short. I start to make 3 AsynchronousConnection in the Main() method. Which call static void AsynchronousConnection(object objectFilename) from there I call the UdpStartClient method.

From UdpStartClient method I send a file with UdpSendXmlFile(fileToSend, udpClient, bytes, CallDuration, out threadId);

After that, I received the answer in a while loop with method UdpReceivedXmlFile("c:\Received" + filename, udpClient, remoteEPReceived, CallDuration, out threadId);

The answer I received in the UdpReceivedXmlFile method, will be save to a file. It is here my problem is, I think. I send 3 file by AsynchronousConnection and received 3 answer from the UDP socket, but the answers does not match the file I send.

For example I send these 3 files.

MessagingText4000.xml

MessagingText4001.xml

MessagingText8.xml

I received the answer randomly, for example:

File MessagingText4000.xml can get the answer from MessagingText8.xml

File MessagingText4001.xml can get the answer from MessagingText4000.xml

File MessagingText8.xml can get the answer from MessagingText4001.xml

Can you help me, so I received the right answer to the right file?

`public delegate void AsyncMethodCall(object objectFilename, int callDuration, out int threadId, out string receivedXmlDataFromTNX);`

```
// Program
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
  Thread newThread;
  newThread = new Thread(AsynchronousConnection);
  newThread.Name = "4001";
  newThread.Start("MessagingText4001.xml");

  newThread = new Thread(AsynchronousConnection);
  newThread.Name = "4000";
  newThread.Start("MessagingText4000.xml");

  newThread = new Thread(AsynchronousConnection);
  newThread.Name = "8";
  newThread.Start("MessagingText8.xml");
}


// Asynchronous Connection 
static void AsynchronousConnection(object objectFilename)
{
  int threadId; string receivedXmlData;
  UdpClass udpClass = new UdpClass();
  AsyncMethodCall caller = new AsyncMethodCall(udpClass.UdpStartClient);
  IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(objectFilename, 500, out threadId, out receivedXmlData, null, null);
  result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
  caller.EndInvoke(out threadId, out receivedXmlData, result);
  result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
}


// UdpClient received 
void UdpReceivedXmlFile(object objectFilename, UdpClient udpClient, IPEndPoint remoteEPReceived, int CallDuration, out int threadId)
{
  Thread.Sleep(CallDuration);
  threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
  try
  {
    // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host. 
    Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEPReceived);
    File.WriteAllText((string)objectFilename, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBytes));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Contact webmaster with this error in UdpReceivedXmlFile:\n " + ex.ToString());
  }
}


// UdpClient send 
void UdpSendXmlFile(string fileToSend, UdpClient udpClient, byte[] bytes, int CallDuration, out int threadId)
{
  Thread.Sleep(CallDuration);
  threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
  try
  {
    // Encode the data string into a byte array 
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(fileToSend);
    // Load XML fil
    string xmlContent = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
    // Send the data through the socket.
    udpClient.Send(msg, msg.Length);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  { Console.WriteLine("Contact webmaster with this error in UdpSendXmlFile:\n " + ex.ToString()); 
  }
}


// UdpStart Client
public void UdpStartClient(object objectFilename, int CallDuration, out int threadId, out string receivedXmlData)
{
  string filename = (string)objectFilename;
  receivedXmlData = null; Thread.Sleep(CallDuration);
  threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
  try
  {
    Console.WriteLine("1: UdpStartClient Async - id: " + threadId + " objectFilename: " + (string)objectFilename);
    fileToSend = fileLocation + filename;
    // Send a file to the UdpSocket 
    UdpSendXmlFile(fileToSend, udpClient, bytes, CallDuration, out threadId);

    TimeSpan maxTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    bool stopwatchStop = false;

    while (stopwatch.Elapsed < maxTime && !stopwatchStop)
    {
      // listed on UdpSocket and save to file 
      UdpReceivedXmlFileDirectToFile("c:\\Received" + filename, udpClient, remoteEPReceived, CallDuration, out threadId);
      attributXMLReceived = ReadXmlAttribut("c:\\Received" + filename, CallDuration, out threadId);

      if ((attributXMLReceived == "Status=Pending") || (attributXMLReceived == "Status=Sent"))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Answer from XMl file:" + attributXMLReceived + " id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "\n");
      }
      else if (attributXMLReceived == "Status=Delivered")
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Answer from XMl file:" + attributXMLReceived + " id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "\n");
        stopwatchStop = true;
      }
      if (stopwatch.Elapsed == maxTime)
        Console.WriteLine("Timeout!");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how UDP works.

UDP is a protocol that provides an unreliable, **unordered** data delivery between devices connected to an IP network. It is generally considered a "layer 4" protocol in the OSI stack. One popular use of UDP is for transport of time-sensitive information, such as Voice over IP. UDP is specified in RFC 768.

http://www.techabulary.com/u/udp/

You either need to use TCP, or be prepared to handle the out-of-order (and possibly completely missing) responses.

[SCTP](http://www.csm.ornl.gov/~dunigan/netperf/sctp.html) is another option for your transmission protocol.

Comment: +1 good answer... stcp is also ordered (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol)

Comment: I agree theoretically with what you've written. But in a good network, or when working on the local machine, I would not expect UDP datagrams to appear in such a random order. Can't it be related to the fact that he has 3 threads that can run in any order? TCP will take care of that, but not only because it will order the packets - but because you'll have separate sessions for each thread.

Comment: The data I received by UDP contains an ID number. When I had this ID number fra the data string I received, then I knew which send package, the received package belonged to.

Comment: Therefore, I came around to keep track of the order the UDP packets.